# Why won't all the pieces of my array display in a java dialog box?

Tags: java, arrays, dialog, joptionpane

So I am trying to write a simple program for my computer science class that takes a list of random numbers from 1-10 and counts how many of each digit there is and prints that to a table, all of which is done in a java dialog box. This is what I have done so far:

```
public class RandomArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String title, temp;
        boolean ok;
        int n = 0;

        title = "Random Number Generator With Counts";
        do {
            ok = true;
            temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter amount of random numbers to generate: ", title, 3);

            try {
                n = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                title = temp + " is not valid!";
                ok = false;
            }   
        }while(!ok);

        int[] numbers = createArray(n);
        int[] counts = countNumbers(numbers);

        displayCounts(counts);

    }

    public static int[] createArray(int n) {
        int[] numbers = new int[n];
        int low = 1, high = 10;

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            numbers[i] = (int)(Math.random()*high) + low;
        }

        return numbers;
    }

    public static int[] countNumbers(int[] numbers) {
        int[] counts = new int[10];

        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            counts[numbers[i]-1]++;
        }

        return counts;
    }

    public static void displayCounts(int[] counts) {
        int message = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            message += counts[i];
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Counts", 1);
    }
}
```

Any advice would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to write a program that generates n random numbers, each between one and ten, and display a frequency table of how many times each digit occurred in the randomly generated numbers, then try changing displayCounts to this:

```
public static void displayCounts(int[] counts) {
        String message = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
            // added in:
            if (counts[i] == 0)
                continue;
            message += (i+1) + " occurred " + counts[i] + " times \n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message, "Counts", 1);
    }
```

counts is the array that tells you how many times each digit was generated. You only care about that frequency value, if it's not 0. Then you can add the frequency to your display string.

I hope this helps in some way :)